# Tips on reading an SQL execution plan for performance tuning

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-execution-plan, query-performance

Background: I have recently just gotten into optimising my SQL queries to get better performance. Previously, I am using ASP.NET Core EF Linq-to-SQL to quickly prototype. Things work correctly, but are obviously not optimised.

I figured I start by looking at the SQLs generated and running them in SQL Management Studio and looking at the actual execution plans of each query.

I know how to read a plan in general, what each tree/node means. Things I'm not sure about I can google relatively easily.

I'm wondering for those query tuning experts out there, are there any experiences you can share which will help me identify *why* a query runs slow?

For example, looking at a JOIN in the execution plan and finding it is not looking up an index is one of the simplest fixes (the only one I can identify right now =D).

What else should I be looking out for?

Comment: Big differences in estimated Vs actual rows. Highest cost operators (though these are based on estimates and can be downright misleading). Scans instead of seeks. Rest of it is down to experience. The live query plan in later versions of SSMS and SQL Server can allow you to see the slow bits in long running queries.

Comment: If you are capturing the LINQ in SQL Profiler for testing, you must always include all of the associated SET options. This is the difference between reproducing a parameter sniffing issue and not. Parameter sniffing is one that is worth looking up. These pop up a lot with optional-where type queries.

Comment: Check out [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) and [Understanding Query Plans](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/understanding-query-plans) for starters